# Multiple types of table rate shipping in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

Anyone know a solution to do multiple types table rate shipping in Magento 2?

In Magento 1 there was a plugin https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-1.html
but for Magento 2 this plugin look like very advanced and its not one time charge, I have only two types table rate like this [image]

Please suggest me a good plugin or any other solutions to work on Magento 2.1.x

Comment: do you found answer for this?

Comment: No prasad, I have purchased a premium plugin instead 
https://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates-for-magento-2.html

Comment: Checkout this one, It has advanced features and compatible with 2.1.x https://magecomp.com/magento-2-matrix-rates.html

Answer (score 1):

This same functionality extension is available here : https://github.com/webshopapps/module-matrixrate

This extension will give you same functionality as webshopmatrix rates as in magento 1.x for Magento 2.x

Comment: Ashish, Thanks for the answer, but its only compatible with M 2.0.x , I am looking for latest.
and this same extension listed here also with Compatibility 2.0
https://marketplace.magento.com/webshopapps-m2matrixrate.html

Answer (score 0):

Riyas,
Check out the extension https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-shipping-table-rates.html which is compatible with 2.x.x versions and allows adding shipping rates based on the destination, shipping weight, and quantity.